# Query posts by user id

Tags: php, wordpress, arguments, author

I'm trying to query post by the user id. The user id in this case will be the author of another post.

I did try the following, however it's not getting the 'author argument'.

```
$author_id = $post->post_author;

$author_query_id = array('author='. $author_id, 'showposts' => '1', 'post_type'=> 'bedrijven', 'post_status' => 'any');
$author_posts_id = new WP_Query($author_query_id);

while($author_posts_id->have_posts()) : $author_posts_id->the_post();


if (get_field('standplaats')) { ?>
<div class="fieldje field-3"><p>
        <span>Standplaats: <?php echo the_field('standplaats'); ?></span>
    </p></div>
 <?php  } 
 endwhile;
```

The user id I'm getting is correct (captured in $author_id). However in the query it just queries the last post of the post type 'Bedrijven', no matter who the author is.

Any idea why this is not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is formatted incorrectly.

```
$author_query_id = array('author' => $author_id, 'showposts' => '1', 'post_type'=> 'bedrijven', 'post_status' => 'any');
```

I removed the `=` from your `author` key.

I'm sure you've seen the [WP_Query documents](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) below, but here is a link to help in the future, just in case.

Comment: Thank you! Strange, I started with that one but then it did not work.. probably a little typo..

Answer (score 1):

use this instead:

```
$author_query_id = array('author'=> $author_id, 'showposts' => '1', 'post_type'=> 'bedrijven', 'post_status' => 'any');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code:

```
<?php

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'bedrijven',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'author'        =>  $current_user->ID,
'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
'order'         =>  'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => 1
);


$author_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

while ( $author_query->have_posts() ) : $author_query->the_post();

$standplaats = get_field('your_field');

if ($standplaats) { ?>

<div class="fieldje field-3">
<p>
<span>Standplaats: <?php echo $standplaats ; ?></span>
</p>
</div>

<?php  }  endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. It would be nice if you give the OP a little bit of details on where the error was.